# Laravel - building an auction site

Tags: laravel

I'm building an auction site using laravel 5 however I'm currently unsure of the best way to go around the bidding process.

I currently have it set-up so that once the user hits a bid button the script runs to place the bid, however if multiple users do this at the same time this causes issues with multiple bids with the same value. I thought about modifying this so that it would queue the bid that way only 1 bid is being processed at once however I believe there will be a better method.

If someone could point me in the correct direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe broadcast an event? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#broadcasting-events

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to simply insert the bid with a high precision timestamp immediately, then check the table using a select and see if its actually a leading bid or not. The table should have an auto incrementing id, so even if two bids have the exact same timestamp, sorting also by id will tell you which one was actually received first.